# Is there a method to evaluate N variables in N functions (vector) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a vector of function `F=(F1,F2…Fn)` and `F1` contains `n` variables `(x1,x2...,xn)`, Same for `F2` to `Fn`. I want to evaluate `F` by a vector `x`, How can write it  using JavaScript?

`F` and `x` are vectors.

```js
F=[[F1],[F2]…[Fn]];
x=[[x1],[x2]…[xn]];
```

I want to return

```js
y = [[F1(x)],[F1(x)]…[Fn(x)]]
```

For example:

```
F=[[x1^2 - x2 -1], [x1 - x2^2 + 1]]
x=[[1], [2]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, it might be useful to provide the expected output of your example (ie, `y = . . . `)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP did not add an attempt to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for from your question, but I thought I would give a shot at giving you an answer.

The first thing I do, is describe an array where each element is a function. Then I create an array of values to pass to each function. Finally, I use the Array `.map` method to pass the values into each function and give the result in a `results` array.

```js
const functions = [
  (x1, x2) => x1 ** 2 - x2 - 2,
  (x1, x2) => x1 -  x2 ** 2 + 1
];

const xVals = [1, 2];

const results = functions.map(fn => fn(...xVals));

console.log(results); //logs [-3, -2]
```